# Adobe Creative SDK blank page

Tags: javascript, adobecreativesdk

I am trying out Adobe Creative SDK, specifically the image editor, but can't seem to get it to work. I have set up a clientId (API key) and added the code to a page as described in the getting started instructions, but all I see is a blank page and no errors in the console. The page is here: https://test-img-editor.firebaseapp.com/test.html

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I needed to move on to the next step to add the image editor UI as explained in the documentation here: https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/web/#/articles/imageeditorui/index.html